# Unreal engine game failing on android 13+ devices

Tags: android, unreal-engine5

I am making an android game using unreal engine version 5.0.3. Target SDK is set to 33. The game is supporting up to android 12 but not on android 13 or above. What is the problem? I am using AdMob inside project. Also all required permissions are provided.

Comment: Please check `adb logcat` for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Arnab Maiti again , again I think is the same issue as your other post-

WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE while using UE 5.2 with API33(Android 13)

change WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE AndroidManifest.xml file to have maxSdkVersion="18" attribute added.
(and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE if that is in the manifest too)

again here is the detailed write up here in the Unreal Engine Forum:

https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/permission-requiired-you-must-approve-this-premission-in-app-settings-storage/656530/21

Comment: And should I ask for those permissions in GameInstance as before?